# How to vectorize this R function when elements depend on other elements in dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

Consider this dataframe :

```
col1 | col2
  1  |  1 
  1  |  2
  1  |  3
  2  |  4
  2  |  5
  2  |  6
```

I want to a new column, say `col3` in the dataframe, which has the following definition : the `ith` element `col3[i]` is the mean of all values of `col2[j]`, for all j such that `col1[i] == col1[j] && i!=j`.

The for loop for it goes like this :

```
for (i in 1:length(data$col2))
{
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for (j in 1:length(data$col1))
    {
        if (data$col1[j] == data$col1[i] && i!=j)
        {
            sum = sum + data$col2[j]
            count = count + 1
        }
    }
    data$col3[i] = sum/count
}
```

The final table is :

```
col1 | col2 | col3
  1  |  1   | 2.5
  1  |  2   | 2
  1  |  3   | 1.5
  2  |  4   | 5.5
  2  |  5   | 5
  2  |  6   | 4.5
```

I could use an apply function, but that would take me pretty much as much time as the for loop, right? Any help with giving a vectorized version of this loop is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(col1) %>%
        mutate(col3 = (sum(col2) - col2)/(n()-1))
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: col1 [2]

   col1  col2  col3
  (int) (int) (dbl)
1     1     1   2.5
2     1     2   2.0
3     1     3   1.5
4     2     4   5.5
5     2     5   5.0
6     2     6   4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$col3 <- with(df1, ave(col2, col1, 
                FUN=function(x) (sum(x)-x)/(length(x)-1)))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, col3 := (sum(col2)-col2)/(.N-1) , col1]
```